# NavBar Custom Height with Search Bar on Right Side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm having a difficult time getting a NavBar to render what I have in mind.

I need a navbar with an increased height (reason because my brand image has a bigger height than the default).

But I also need all menu elements (BUTTON, LI, A, FORM ELEMENTS, NAVBAR-TEXT, NAVBAR-RIGHT) to respect the new height and to properly vertically center in the navbar.

**Can someone provide some example HTML/CSS for what needs to be changed?**
I have done lots of searching online and there seems to be nothing obvious.

The BootStrap site shows documentation on how to define a navbar, but nothing that I could find regarding height changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting your brand image within the navbar-brand div then you can change the height to the height you need (or height of the brand image) using css:

```
.navbar-brand {
    height: 80px;
}
```

To align the navbar elements vertically you can give the navbar a top margin to what you need also using css:

```
.navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

You will have to use css breakpoints if these need to be changed for smaller devices.